# proxy-revalidate http header

Tags: http, caching, proxy

I've been trying to work out why some legacy configuration makes use of the proxy-revalidate directive of the Cache-Control HTTP header field. I came across [this](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/ange/archives/archives-96/http-wg-archive/2775.html) archive post by the author of this part of the HTTP spec in which he acknowledges that the directive isn't useful for its intended purpose (described in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4)). Is this still the general opinion, and can the directive be put to any other use? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might have misunderstood what Jeffrey Mogul was trying to say. He didn’t say *proxy-revalidate* isn’t useful. He just said that there is a use case where *proxy-revalidate* is not sufficient.

In this use case, a shared cache should be forced to revalidate any response with the origin server before using an entry to respond a subsequent request, *no matter whether it is still fresh or already stale*.

This use case cannot be denoted with the current set of directives as *proxy-revalidate* does only apply to stale responses and *max-age* applies to both non-shared and shared caches. This is why he suggests an additional directive, *proxy-maxage*, that can specify a different lifetime for shared caches.

Comment: Thanks for responding. My understanding was the same as yours; however, after posting I realized that s-maxage=0 makes the intended use case from the spec possible. Do you know if proxy-maxage was added to the spec as s-maxage subsequent to the archived discussion? Also, can you suggest any other use cases to which the proxy-revalidate directive might be applied?